# Deleting in EF Code first causes navigational properties to be set to null and empty

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I noticed something interesting when I was performing a delete using EF code first. I use the following domain model:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Playlist> Playlists { get; set; }
}

public class Playlist
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
}
```

The model is configured using:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Playlists).WithRequired(x => x.User).Map(x => x.MapKey("UserId"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>().HasMany(x => x.Tracks).WithRequired(x => x.Playlist).Map(x => x.MapKey("PlaylistId"));
}
```

I use a generic repository:

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
    Database.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
}
```

I also have a dto that looks like:

```
public class PlaylistDTO
{
    public PlaylistDTO(Playlist playlist)
    {
        Id = playlist.Id;
        Title = playlist.Title;
        User = playlist.User.Name;
    }
}
```

In one of my services I am trying to do the following:

```
public PlaylistDTO Delete(long id)
{
    Playlist playlist = playlistRepository.GetById(id);
    playlistRepository.Delete(playlist);
    unitOfWork.Commit();

    return PlaylistDTO(playlist);
}
```

This code fails. When I stepped through the debugger I noticed something interesting. The moment I call playlistRepository.Delete the navigational properties (User and Tracks) get set to null and empty respectively. Playlist however stays in memory. So when I pass in the playlist to the DTO the code will fail when it is trying to access playlist.User.Name. I wanted to pass this data to the client to display a verification.

Is this behavior correct? Is this by design?

Comment: I believe it's by design. There are many other situations where the context modifies a navigation property internally which you didn't touch explicitely, for instance if you have both sides of a relationship exposed in the model and you change one side the context will update the other side internally (it might rely on enabled change detection, not sure). Your Delete will probably also remove the playlist from the User PlayLists collection. Why clearing the navigation properties of a deleted entity is useful or necessary or convenient or safer or whatever? I don't know. Would interest me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how EF works. The problem is that your `Playlist` forms entity graph with other relations and EF uses very simple rule for tracking entity graphs: All entities in the graph must be tracked - there cannot be reference to entity which is not tracked. I don't give you reference to description of this rule, it is just my observation but I didn't find any single exception to this rule.

Edit: **Updated version - I just checked internal implementation and relations are indeed nulled during calling Delete**

So what happened in your code.

- You marked your `Playlist` as deleted
- **EF passes delete operation to the state manager which does the fixup - it will null all relations**
- You saved changes to the database
- Because there are no cascade deletes from `Playlist` all related objects remain undeleted
- Once you saved changes EF internally accepted them and set change tracker to current state
- Because the current state of `Playlist` is non existing (deleted in the database) it was detached from the context
- <strike>Detaching has broken entity graph and EF fixed it by modifying navigation properties on both ends</strike>

The code responsible for nulling from `System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.Delete(doFixup)` (`doFixup` is true) - the class is internal:

```
if (doFixup && (base.State != EntityState.Deleted))
{
    this.RelationshipManager.NullAllFKsInDependentsForWhichThisIsThePrincipal();
    this.NullAllForeignKeys();
    this.FixupRelationships();
}
```

In your scenario this should have simple workaround - create DTO before you delete entity.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Then it happens actually after SaveChanges and not after Delete as he wrote in the question.

Comment: @Slauma: Sounds reasonable but actually it was a bad answer - I edited it with result of my research.

Comment: Hm, for the first version I understood the need to fix the relationships. Here I am not sure why they already have to be fixed when calling Delete. Well, it's just how it works and something to keep in mind. There will be some reason why this strategy is benefitial or even necessary.

Comment: Years passed and it's still there. In my scenario it happens upon `Remove`, just after `SaveChanges`. Since I have an internal auditing hooked on `SaveChanges` I get null values but interestingly - only on optional (nullable) references. Also, the change is in memory only, luckily it's not persisted. Frankly, I don't see any reason for this behavior.