# Why does EF4 null out relationships prior to removing committing the record deletion?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When my application requests I delete an entity, I want to delete the uploaded file that's associated with that entity.  So I have the following code:

```
        TestRequest req = _context.TestRequests
                                  .Where(x => x.id == id)
                                  .Include(x => x.TestRequestRuns)
                                  .Include(x => x.TestPlanFile)
                                  .Single();

        _context.TestRequests.Remove(req);
        _context.UploadedFiles.Remove(req.TestPlanFile);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

This code exceptions on the removal of the uploaded file.  Debugging shows that calling `_context.TestRequests.Remove(req)` makes the `req.TestPlanFile` property `null`, thus causing the exception (you can't remove a null uploaded file).  This does NOT clear out the `req.TestPlanFileId` property.

In order to perform this deletion you have to mark the child entities for removal before you mark the main entity for removal.  This also means that marking an item for removal *MUST* be the last thing you do with that entities data, because you won't (easily at least) be able to access the child entities for further manipulation (not always will you delete child entities, for example if the uploaded file is used by multiple test plans).

Does anyone have any reasoning why the stripping of properties is ocurring prior to using `SaveChanges()`?  I would have thought `Remove()`'s only function was to tell EF that it needs to delete the row when the changes are saved, but apparently it's doing much more.

Comment: +1 Because I'd like to see some reasoning behind this too.

Comment: Yes, `Remove` is doing much more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778431/deleting-in-ef-code-first-causes-navigational-properties-to-be-set-to-null-and-em/6782744#6782744